# Is there a way to throttle nsurlsessiond/cloudd?

Tags: macos, icloud, network, daemons

I have been looking for a way to permanently throttle these two processes.  By default, they are all or nothing processes killing my network connection unless I manually "pause uploads" for iPhotos (nsurlsessiond) or killing/logging out of iCloud for cloudd.

I don't mind them running in the background but would like to control their bandwidth consumption without killing them off completely.  Similar to the way that I can throttle oneDrive upload/download (which to my chagrin, Microsoft does this better than Apple in this case!)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

This is not a throttling solution, but can alleviate some problems.

Use Activity monitor, Network tab to find out the PID of `nsurlsessiond` with User `_nsurlsessiond`.

In Terminal, run

```
sudo kill -STOP 1234
```

where 1234 is the PID you found above.

When you want to run it,

```
sudo kill -CONT 1234
```

Make sure you got the correct PID and not stop other crucial processes.